# Is it possible to sort (order_by) results of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sorting, many-to-many, laravel, laravel-4

I have a couple tables in my database which have a many-to-many relationship.  I have linked them in the Model as so...

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'user_tag')->withPivot('otherStuff');
}
```

I would like the results to be sorted alphabetically, with something like this...

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'user_tag')->withPivot('otherStuff')->order_by('name', 'asc');
}
```

I tried that code, but Laravel 4 failed and complained that order_by didn't exist.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer finally. The correct method is orderBy, not order_by.